# Display Table and Form in Django View

Tags: python, django, forms, view

I am attempting to return a form and table in the same view so that they appear in the same screen.

I know that the below code does not work, it is to illustrate what I want to do - I have my `CreateManifestForm` and `manifests = Manifests.objects.all()` should populate the table which is present in the template.  The problem is when I render this - it shows the form, and just the blank table. I have populated the table using a separate view so I know that it is set up properly on its own, but how can I render `{'form': form}` and `context` at the same time?

Views.py:

```
def add_manifest(request):
    manifests = Manifests.objects.all()
    context = {
        'manifests' : manifests,
    }

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST)


        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('display_orders')

    else:
        form = CreateManifestForm()
        return render(request, 'add_manifest.html', {'form': form})
        return render(request, 'add_manifest.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just return everything you need in the context. You have 2 returns there so the second one never happens.

You'll need to do;

```
def add_manifest(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('display_orders')

    # Leave this down here so that you don't hit 
    # the database for manifests on a POST when 
    # the form is valid, because that returns above
    form = CreateManifestForm()
    manifests = Manifests.objects.all()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'manifests': manifests,
    }

    return render(request, 'add_manifest.html', context)
```